# Discord Bot - How to delete the second to last recent message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm a newbie so I would like to apologize in advance if this sounds like a stupid question. I couldn't figure out how to make my discord bot programmed in python delete the second to last recent message.

I know that there are various ways to delete messages upon user input like: `await message.channel.purge(limit=1)` which simply removes the latest message in the server based on different conditions in the if-statement set up above it. However, I'm not sure how to skip the latest message and remove the second message in line.

For example, if I have two messages currently present in the discord channel:

```
# Message One (sent before)
# Message Two (sent after)
```

Message One is sent before message Two and I would like to remove Message One without the removal of Message Two. Message One has a special part (content) attached to it, but I couldn't find any methods that would remove a message based on the message's content.

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
messageCount = 1
async for msg in message.channel.history(limit = 2):    # Gets the last two messages
    if messageCount == 1:   # Skipping the last message
        messageCount += 1
        continue

    if 'my content' in msg.content.lower():     # Check if the message has some content
        await msg.delete()  # Deleting that message
```